# ReactJS Set state from json data inner array - Multiple Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have a json file that is an array that stores another field that contains another array that I want. I have an ajax request that stores the `pitching` field into a state array `pitchers` I have two buttons that when clicked will pass a value equal to the `team_flag` attribute in the json file.

```
<button className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'home')}>{homeTeamName}</button>
<button className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'away')}>{awayTeamName}</button>
```

And the method:

```
handleClick: function(teamFlag) {
    // setState of pitchers to whichever team is clicked (home, away)
    // this.setState({ pitchers: this.state.pitchers.teamFlag})???
    console.log(teamFlag);
}
```

How do I set the `pitchers` **state** so that it will take the `pitcher` array that corresponds to the `team_flag` that was clicked? (i.e. If I click on homeTeam it will store the `pitcher` array that is under the `"team_flag": "home"`) Below is the json file

```
     "pitching":[
        {
           "pitcher":[
              {"name": "Billy", "hand": "right"}
           ],
           "team_flag":"away",
        },
        {
           "pitcher":[
              {"name": "Joe", "hand": "right"}
           ],
           "team_flag":"home",
        }
     ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the entire "pitching" array in the state under the `pitching` key you could something like:

```
var pitchers = this.state.pitching.find(function(team) {
  return team.team_flag === teamFlag;
});

this.setState({ pitchers: pitchers.pitcher });
```

If it is only for presentation purposes I wouldn't save the result in the state, instead I'd save the teamFlag and call the mentioned code in the render method.

React is smart enough to know that if teamFlag or the pitching array changes then it needs to re-render.

EDIT:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        // make your ajax request
        // and when the request is finished
        this.setState({ loading: true });
    }

    handleClick(ev, flag) {
        this.setState({ flag: flag });
    }

    render() {
        let homeTeamName = 'Home';
        let awayTeamName = 'Away';
        let selectedFlag = this.state.flag;
        let pitchers = this.state.pitching.find(function(team) {
            return team.team_flag === selectedFlag;
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {!this.state.loading ? 
                  <div>
                    <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'home')}>{homeTeamName}</button>
                    <button className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'away')}>{awayTeamName}</button> 
                  </div>:
                  null
                }
                // render using the pitchers array
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: It is only for presentation purposes (i.e. I need to fetch the data inside `pitcher` and display the data in there). How would it know when it is clicked if the above code does not go into a `handleClick` method?

Comment: My bad, I didn't properly express myself. The idea would be to save the flag in the state inside your `handleClick` instead of saving the pitchers. I'll update my answer with a sample component...

Comment: Thanks @nbermudezs, just wondering what will set change the state of loading since it's true the entire time?

Comment: Oops, typo, `this.setState({ loading: true });` should have been `false`. Sorry about that. Note it says: "when the request finishes"

Comment: Hmm when I try the above method you posted, I am receiving an error when building it: `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` The divs are enclosed however...

Comment: This is encompassed between two divs: i.e. inside `{!this.state.loading ? <div></div> <div></div>:null }`

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding another `{!this.state.loading }` ternary inside the other div. Is this the best way to proceed?

Comment: The pitchers constant above also seems to only return a boolean value when I do a console.log? How would it store the array instead?

Comment: You are right about the pitchers. I updated the answer with the right function (should have been `find` instead of `some`). About the enclosing tag, what other div did you enclose?

Comment: Inside the loading state the first set of divs had {someVar} while the second set contained {anotherVar} not sure about the error produced but, it was fixed by enclosing each set of div inside a new ternary loading state.